# Show only next three business dates in datepicker

Tags: jquery

I need display only next three business days . I have used following code .

```
$('#txtDate').datepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: '+3',
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
            });
```

Its working fine. But some condition was not satisfied . For example today date 12-03-2016 , next 3 business days means its show only 2 days

Comment: because you disabled weekends

Comment: yes, I disabled weekends days . But I need show 3 days . If suppose the next three days contains sunday means skip the day .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.you can optimize this logic if it helps you

```js
$('#txtDate').datepicker({
  minDate: 0,
  stepMonths: 0,
  beforeShowDay: function(d) {
    var today = new Date(); //new Date("Mar 15 2016");

    if (d.getDay() === 0) {
      return [false];
    } else if ((today.getDay() >= 0 && today.getDay() < 4) && (d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 1 || d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 2 || d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 3)) {
      return [true];
    } else if (today.getDay() == 4 && (d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 1 || d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 2 || d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 4)) {

      return [true];

    } else if (today.getDay() == 5 && (d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 1 || d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 3 || d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 4)) {

      return [true];

    } else if (today.getDay() == 6 && (d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 2 || d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 3 || d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 4)) {

      return [true];

    } else {
      return [false];
    }


  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type=text id='txtDate' />
```

Example with all dates in a week

```js
$('.txtDate').datepicker({
  minDate: 0,
  stepMonths: 0,
  beforeShowDay: function(d) {
    var today = new Date($(this).val());

    if (d.getDay() === 0) {
      return [false];
    } else if ((today.getDay() >= 0 && today.getDay() < 4) && (d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 1 || d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 2 || d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 3)) {
      return [true];
    } else if (today.getDay() == 4 && (d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 1 || d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 2 || d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 4)) {

      return [true];

    } else if (today.getDay() == 5 && (d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 1 || d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 3 || d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 4)) {

      return [true];

    } else if (today.getDay() == 6 && (d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 2 || d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 3 || d.getDate() == today.getDate() + 4)) {

      return [true];

    } else {
      return [false];
    }


  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type=text class='txtDate' value='Mar 13 2016' />
<input type=text class='txtDate' value='Mar 14 2016' />
<input type=text class='txtDate' value='Mar 15 2016' />
<input type=text class='txtDate' value='Mar 16 2016' />
<input type=text class='txtDate' value='Mar 17 2016' />
<input type=text class='txtDate' value='Mar 18 2016' />
<input type=text class='txtDate' value='Mar 19 2016' />
```